# How to restore Ubuntu from a USB Drive

Tags: backup, chromebook

I'm running crouton and Ubuntu on a Chromebook. I want to reinstall Ubuntu from a backup of the chroot which I have on a USB drive but can't figure out how to make this work.
Usually I copy the backup file to the downloads directory and run: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -f trusty.gz`
but in this case the backup file is too big.
I've tried `sudo sh crouton -f /media/removable/16GB\/trusty.tar.gz` but get

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh crouton -f /media/removable/16GB\/trusty.tar.gz
sh: 0: Can't open crouton
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same problem this did the trick

```
sudo edit-chroot -f /media/removable/your_path_on_drive -r chrootname
```

Thanks to https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Crouton-Command-Cheat-Sheet